# How can I use multiple needs_string_links in order to render an option depending on its content?

Tags: python-sphinx

### Question

How can I form a `needs_string_links` entry ([1](https://sphinx-needs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#needs-string-links)) in `sphinx-needs` in such a way that for one and the same need option I can have several rendering choices?

(Such as if regex 1 matches, render the option like this, if regex 2 matches like that, and so on and so forth.)

### Context

Say I have two sphinx-needs of the same type, such as this:

```
.. need:: Need 1
    :id: 1
    :owner: john-doe_user

.. need:: Need 2
    :id: 2
    :owner: jane.doe@mail.com
```

Note that the format of the option entry for `owner` differs, the one in Need 1 is meant to represent a github user identification, the one in  Need 2 is a plain email address.

According to [1](https://sphinx-needs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#needs-string-links) there exists the option to render the `owner` option as a link when processed by sphinx. As I want to allow both formats, but still want clickable links, I am hoping to write clever `needs_link_strings` to capture these cases*:

```
needs_string_links = {
    'render_github_user': {
        'regex': r"^(?P<value>.+_user)$",  # hypotheses: all github users end in _user
        'link_url': "https://github.com/orgs/MyOrg/teams/" + "{{value}}",
        'link_name': "{{value}}",
        'options': ['owner']
    },
    'render_email_address': {
        'regex': r"^(?P<value>.+@.+)$",  # poor man's email-regex
        'link_url' : "mailto:" + "{{value}}",
        'link_name': "{{value}}"
        'options': ['owner']
    },
}
```

### Expected Behavior:

Need 1 is rendered in a way such when I click on `john-doe_user` I get to the resp. github user profile.
Need 2 is rendered such that clicking on `jane.doe@mail.com` triggers my mail system

### Obeserved Behavior:

Only one form of entry gets rendered, the other is ignored. It's not even a malformed link, it simply is ignored. :'(

I am not sure about this, but it *might* be that order matters, i.e. only the first rendering description in `needs_string_links` is used (i.e. if the regex matches then the link is build, else plain text is shown) and the second entry is then discarded, ignored, or stepped over... I say *might* as I couldn't reproduce this cleanly, sometimes order seems to matter, sometimes it doesn't :/

--

*: yes, I know that the regexes aren't the nicest ones around, but please bear with me :)